# Not able to login to a webpage using excel, error 424 object required

Tags: vba, excel, authentication, internet-explorer, dom

I am trying to login to this webpage, https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/ecustomer/JSP/QryInsight.jsp
using VBA. Debugging shows me that the VBA throws an error 424 object required when username line is active (apparently it is not able to fill the username data).

Here's the code:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate ("https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/ecustomer/JSP/QryInsight.jsp")
    With ie.document
        .getElementById("txtUserId").Value = "ABCDE"
        .getElementById("txtPassword").Value = "ABCDE"
        .getElementById("submit").Click
    End With

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with debugging the problem while logging in to the given webpage?

Comment: That page has frames and the URL you provided is the top frame. The real URL for the login part is: https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/ecustomer/JSP/LoginNew.jsp

Comment: Assuming Logan is correct, you will want to navigate to the document of the frame, and then get the element by ID. You should be able to get the frame by either the name, class, or ID.

Comment: Try using the same code in VBS using .getElementsByName("txtUserId").value

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the below example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim oIE As Object

    Set oIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
    With oIE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate ("https://www.fois.indianrail.gov.in/ecustomer/JSP/QryInsight.jsp")
        Do While .ReadyState < 4 Or .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        With .Document
            Do While .ReadyState <> "complete"
                DoEvents
            Loop
            With .parentWindow.frames("frmCUMain").document
                .getElementsByName("txtUserId")(0).Value = "ABCDE"
                .getElementsByName("txtPassword")(0).Value = "ABCDE"
                .getElementsByName("cmdLogin")(0).Click
            End With
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```